# Get contents of temporary uploaded file

Tags: 8, files

I've uploaded a file in a custom form and I can retrieve the file instance like this:

```
  $fid = $form_state->getValue('file')[0];
  $file = File::load($fid);
```

How can I get the contents of the file?

```
kint(file_get_contents($file->url()));
```

Returns false. If I visit the link manually, it gets downloaded.

Answer (score 9):

You can't get the file from `$form_state->getValue()`. You have to upload the file first to the file table as temporary file with `file_save_upload()`. Then you can load the file content locally from `$file->getFileUri()`.

```
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $validators = ['file_validate_extensions' => ['txt']];
    if ($file = file_save_upload('file', $validators, FALSE, 0)) {
      $data = file_get_contents($file->getFileUri());
      drupal_set_message($data);
    }

  }
```